# ERROR unable to resolve dependency tree when installing ngrx store with Angular 13

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I have an issue when I use this command:

```
ng add @ngrx/store@latest
```

I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: ngstore-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@13.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~13.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"^12.0.0" from @ngrx/store@12.5.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@ngrx/store
npm ERR!   @ngrx/store@"12.5.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See ...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

Versions tha I am using:
    Angular CLI: 13.0.1
    Node: 16.13.0
    Package Manager: npm 8.1.3
```

Any idea what causes the issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `@angular/core` at version 13, but `@ngrx/store` has support until Angular 12.

If you install the `latest` tag it will grab `12.5.1` which does not work in your case.

You should consider `ng add @ngrx/store@next` to grab the version `13.0.0-beta.0`

---

You can see everything with `npm show @ngrx/store`

```
dist-tags:
beta: 6.0.0-beta.2   latest: 12.5.1       next: 13.0.0-beta.0  v8-lts: 8.6.1        v9-lts: 9.2.1
```

Comment: I got the same error as Michael, and here is `npm show @ngrx/store` result:    
 `@ngrx/store@13.2.0 | MIT | deps: 1 | versions: 109`

Comment: and here is dist-tags:
`beta: 6.0.0-beta.2  latest: 13.2.0      next: 13.0.0        v8-lts: 8.6.1       v9-lts: 9.2.1       `

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use this command:

```
 npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple solution is to remove the `@latest` tag. You can just run the command as `ng add @ngrx/store`. This way the most latest compatible version of the package will be installed.