# What it means in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material, ionic4, ionic-native

I am facing error as below when i try to execute ng add @angular/material in my ionic project. please let me know what it tries to say? what need to be changed. this

````
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~13.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/material@13.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     @angular/material@"13.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"13.1.1" from @angular/animations@13.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/material@13.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     @angular/material@"13.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.```
````

Comment: downgrade your nodejs version

Comment: already downgraded into v14.17.5

Comment: what ionic version youre using? Maybe you just need to use older material version?

Comment: ionic 4.1.0, node 14.17.5, npm 8.3.0, gradle 7.0, angular cli 13.1.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904564/error-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-when-installing-ngrx-store-with-angular

Answer (score 0):

try to run `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` first

Comment: it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Your project automatically use angular 13 version for each angular dependency.
Ionic 5 use angular 12 version So You should use @angular/material version 12.
Check Your ion-angular version from package.json then use same version angular material.

Comment: i am using ionic 6 and ionic 4.1.0, node 14.17.5, npm 8.3.0, gradle 7.0, angular cli 13.1.2